# Articles and Categories - The efficient way

Tags: php, mysql

I want to add categories to my website - but with more complex sorting.

Lets say I have article **a**. now, I want **a** to be under main category **a**, but also on category **c** thats its parent is **b**.

I thought of doing it like this:
An article would have a **main category** field, and also **parent_ids**

**parent_ids** would be every category this item is belong to. 
my problem is: lets say i have: **parent_ids: |1|5|2|7|**.

now i am in category id - **7**.

how would my select query look like?

```
select * from categories where parent_ids LIKE '%|7|%'
```

is it efficient? is there a better idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Never store multiple values in one column. All column values in a normalized database should be atomic (single-valued).

The relationship between `articles` and `categories` is **many-to-many**. That means you should have a separate table, such as `article_category (article_id, category_id)` containing one row for each category each article is in.

Comment: Thanks! that would do it. :-)

Comment: Many-to-many: There are multiple sources (articles) and multiple targets (categories)